# log is not properly printed in console in ADF mobile

Tags: oracle-adf

I write code in start() in LifeCycleListenerImpl.

```
System.err.println("logging in sys");

Utility.ApplicationLogger.logp(Level.SEVERE,
LifeCycleListenerImpl.class.getName(),
"onTestMessage",
"embedded warning message 1");
Logger.getLogger(Utility.APP_LOGNAME).logp(Level.SEVERE,
this.getClass().getName(),
"onTestMessage",
"embedded warning message 2");
Logger.getLogger("oracle.adfmf.application").logp(Level.SEVERE,
this.getClass().getName(),
"onTestMessage",
"embedded warning message 3");
```

And i got following output in console window. But i am not under stand that what is this ?

```
May 6 14:41:29 evosys-iMacs-iMac.local Application1[1771]: Obj-C [CH-1, State=created ableToSend=Yes] Send message VMMessage [
type: Plain[0x00]
prinorty: 2
channelID: 1
messageID: 11
length: 225
body: {41, 44, 46, 4D, 53, 47, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 35, 30, 35, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 31, 38, 39, 7B, 22, 63, 6C, 61, 73, 73, 6E, 61, 6D, 65, 22, 3A, 22, 6F, 72, 61, 63, 6C, 65, 2E, 61, 64, 66, 6D, 66, 2E, 66, 72, 61, 6D, 65, 77, 6F, 72, 6B, 2E, 61, 70, 69, 2E, 4D, 6F, 64, 65, 6C, 22, 2C, 22, 70, 61, 72, 61, 6D, 73, 22, 3A, 5B, 5B, 22, 23, 7B, 61, 70, 70, 6C, 69, 63, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 53, 63, 6F, 70, 65, 2E, 63, 6F, 6E, 66, 69, 67, 75, 72, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 2E, 61, 6D, 78, 54, 72, 61, 6E, 73, 69, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 4D, 6F, 64, 65, 7D, 22, 2C, 22, 23, 7B, 61, 70, 70, 6C, 69, 63, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 53, 63, 6F, 70, 65, 2E, 63, 6F, 6E, 66, 69, 67, 75, 72, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 2E, 61, 6D, 78, 54, 72, 61, 6E, 73, 69, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 4D, 6F, 64, 65, 7D, 22, 5D, 5D, 2C, 22, 6D, 65, 74, 68, 6F, 64, 22, 3A, 22, 67, 65, 74, 56, 61, 6C, 75, 65, 22, 7D}
]
May 6 14:41:29 evosys-iMacs-iMac.local Application1[1771]: Obj-C [CH-1, State=created ableToSend=Yes] Send message VMMessage [
type: Plain[0x00]
prinorty: 2
channelID: 1
messageID: 11
length: 136
body: {41, 44, 46, 4D, 53, 47, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 35, 30, 36, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 31, 30, 30, 7B, 22, 63, 6C, 61, 73, 73, 6E, 61, 6D, 65, 22, 3A, 22, 6F, 72, 61, 63, 6C, 65, 2E, 61, 64, 66, 6D, 66, 2E, 66, 72, 61, 6D, 65, 77, 6F, 72, 6B, 2E, 61, 70, 69, 2E, 4D, 6F, 64, 65, 6C, 22, 2C, 22, 70, 61, 72, 61, 6D, 73, 22, 3A, 5B, 22, 66, 65, 61, 74, 75, 72, 65, 31, 2F, 6C, 6F, 67, 2E, 61, 6D, 78, 22, 5D, 2C, 22, 6D, 65, 74, 68, 6F, 64, 22, 3A, 22, 73, 65, 74, 43, 6F, 6E, 74, 65, 78, 74, 22, 7D}
]
May  6 14:04:06 evosys-iMacs-iMac.local manager[1443] <Warning>: Obj-C [CH-9, State=created ableToSend=Yes]: Waiting for Message 
May  6 14:04:06 evosys-iMacs-iMac.local manager[1443] <Warning>: Obj-C [CH-1, State=created ableToSend=Yes]: Message arrived - VMMessage [
        type: Plain[0x00]
        prinorty: 2
        channelID: -1
        messageID: 3
        length: 340
        body: {41, 44, 46, 4D, 53, 47, 20, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 35, 31, 30, 20, 20, 20, 35, 31, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 33, 30, 34, 7B, 22, 72, 65, 73, 75, 6C, 74, 22, 3A, 5B, 7B, 22, 2E, 74, 79, 70, 65, 22, 3A, 22, 6F, 72, 61, 63, 6C, 65, 2E, 61, 64, 66, 6D, 66, 2E, 66, 72, 61, 6D, 65, 77, 6F, 72, 6B, 2E, 63, 6F, 6E, 74, 72, 61, 63, 74, 2E, 61, 64, 66, 2E, 4E, 61, 6D, 65, 56, 61, 6C, 75, 65, 50, 61, 69, 72, 22, 2C, 22, 76, 61, 6C, 75, 65, 22, 3A, 7B, 22, 2E, 6E, 75, 6C, 6C, 22, 3A, 74, 72, 75, 65, 7D, 2C, 22, 6E, 61, 6D, 65, 22, 3A, 22, 23, 7B, 61, 70, 70, 6C, 69, 63, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 53, 63, 6F, 70, 65, 2E, 63, 6F, 6E, 66, 69, 67, 75, 72, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 2E, 61, 6D, 78, 54, 72, 61, 6E, 73, 69, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 4D, 6F, 64, 65, 7D, 22, 7D, 2C, 7B, 22, 2E, 74, 79, 70, 65, 22, 3A, 22, 6F, 72, 61, 63, 6C, 65, 2E, 61, 64, 66, 6D, 66, 2E, 66, 72, 61, 6D, 65, 77, 6F, 72, 6B, 2E, 63, 6F, 6E, 74, 72, 61, 63, 74, 2E, 61, 64, 66, 2E, 4E, 61, 6D, 65, 56, 61, 6C, 75, 65, 50, 61, 69, 72, 22, 2C, 22, 76, 61, 6C, 75, 65, 22, 3A, 7B, 22, 2E, 6E, 75, 6C, 6C, 22, 3A, 74, 72, 75, 65, 7D, 2C, 22, 6E, 61, 6D, 65, 22, 3A, 22, 23, 7B, 61, 70, 70, 6C, 69, 63, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 53, 63, 6F, 70, 65, 2E, 63, 6F, 6E, 66, 69, 67, 75, 72, 61, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 2E, 61, 6D, 78, 54, 72, 61, 6E, 73, 69, 74, 69, 6F, 6E, 4D, 6F, 64, 65, 7D, 22, 7D, 5D, 7D}
    ]
May  6 14:04:06 evosys-iMacs-iMac.local manager[1443] <Warning>: Obj-C [CH-1, State=created ableToSend=Yes]: Waiting for Message 
May  6 14:04:06 evosys-iMacs-iMac.local manager[1443] <Warning>: Obj-C [CH-1, State=created ableToSend=Yes]: Message arrived - VMMessage [
        type: Plain[0x00]
        prinorty: 2
        channelID: -1
        messageID: 3
        length: 137
        body: {41, 44, 46, 4D, 53, 47, 20, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 35, 31, 31, 20, 20, 20, 35, 31, 31, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 31, 30, 31, 7B, 22, 72, 65, 73, 75, 6C, 74, 22, 3A, 5B, 5D, 2C, 22, 64, 61, 74, 61, 43, 68, 61, 6E, 67, 65, 45, 76, 65, 6E, 74, 22, 3A, 7B, 22, 76, 61, 72, 69, 61, 62, 6C, 65, 43, 68, 61, 6E, 67, 65, 73, 22, 3A, 7B, 22, 76, 69, 65, 77, 53, 63, 6F, 70, 65, 22, 3A, 7B, 22, 2E, 6E, 75, 6C, 6C, 22, 3A, 74, 72, 75, 65, 7D, 7D, 2C, 22, 70, 72, 6F, 76, 69, 64, 65, 72, 43, 68, 61, 6E, 67, 65, 73, 22, 3A, 7B, 7D, 7D, 7D}
    ]
```

so,  My question is that i am printing "logging in sys", and why it is not printed in console.

Comment: oops, i added a reply, but i overlooked the ADF Mobile part. ignore that response :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iPhone Simulator 6.1, check the file:
/Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications//Documents/logs/application.log

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure logging. Don't forget to ensure that the deployment mode is set to debug.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/debugging.htm#BABCBIHI